# How to select an item from a list using Selenium WebDriver with java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, automation

am trying to select an option from the list but not able to select anything with below code. It doesnt throw any error just move to next line and perform further actions.(HTML and UI link below)

```
`    List options = element.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='awdui-list']/li"));    
for (WebElement opt : options)    
{​​System.out.println(opt);   
if (opt.getText().equals("APP"))   
 {​​executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", opt);   
return;
}
​​}​​ `
```

[ [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnM4l.png][1]

[  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNreW.jpg][1]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `opt.click();` inside your code. This will work.

Comment: No it didn't. Its not even printing me the list of all the values :(. I think xpath is not correct.

Comment: I think you should try simple for loop

Comment: I am trying same only. But problem is with xpath I think.

Comment: I just noticed the xpath. This will not work. Try generating your own custom XPath.

Comment: That what  I am looking for,If someone can suggest me the correct xpath for this.Thanks

Comment: Generating XPaths is easy, feel free to ping me at abhishek.puri@hotmail.com